# { discord.js } TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a /verify command on my bot, but when I do it I get this error

```
user.role.add(verifyrole);
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In djs v12 it's `.roles.add`
[roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)

Comment: you have `user.role` not `user.roles` with an 's'.

Answer (score 0):

In v12 its

```
User.roles.add(verifyrole)
```